# Error getting json data, ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, node.js

I'm trying to get a data from server without refreshing  the page using `ajax`, So the problem the data come like a text not like `json` data

my code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/search?key=" + QUERY + "",
    success: function (reslt) {
        console.log(reslt);
        console.log(reslt.length);
    }
});
```

and the data on the server:

im using nodejs and express framework the code:

```
router.get('/search', function (req, res) {
    tab = ['08:00', '09:00', '10:00', '11:00'];
    res.end(JSON.stringify(tab));
});
```

why when i do `console.log(reslt[3]);` it's give me `8` , should give me `10:00`

Comment: Add `dataType: 'json'` to the `$.ajax()` call.

Comment: Add `dataType:'json'` to your [ajax call](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Use JSON.stringify at server side and use JSON.parse in successhandler to access the indices of the data.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
dataType: 'json'
```

If your response is JSON, always set the `datatype` to `json`. Do it like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "http://localhost:8080/search?key=" + QUERY + "",
    success: function (reslt) {
        console.log(reslt);
        console.log(reslt.length);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `dataType` and `contentType` attribute in your `ajax` request

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/search?key=" + QUERY + "",
    success: function (reslt) {
        console.log(reslt);
        console.log(reslt.length);
    }
});
```

Comment: the `contentType` is likely not required. `contentType` is the type of data your **sending**, not **receiving**.